# How to update ngModel from directive?

Tags: angular, input, dom-events, angular2-directives

I've created a directive to limit the length of `input` field `type=number`.

// Input

```
<input min="1" appLimitTo [limit]="5" type="number" name="property" [(ngModel)]="property">
```

// Directive

```
import {Directive, HostListener, Input} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appLimitTo]',
})
export class LimitToDirective {

    @Input() limit: number;
    @Input() ngModel: any;

    @HostListener('input', ['$event'])
    onInput(e) {
        if (e.target.value.length >= +this.limit) {
            e.target.value = (e.target.value).toString().slice(0, this.limit - 1);
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

It works fine if we enter the value through the keyboard. But the problem arises when if I copy & paste `12345678913465789` this number, this line `e.target.value = (e.target.value).toString().slice(0, this.limit - 1);` shorten it to the limit, but the `ngModel` still contains `12345678913465789` value. How to update this ngModel value?

Please help.

PS - What should I add in my directive to meet the requirement?

Comment: Angular directives @output

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can inject `NgControl` into your own directive. You can then listen to the control `valueChanges` event.

limit-to.directive.ts

```
import {Directive, HostListener, Input, OnInit, OnDestroy} from '@angular/core';
import {NgControl} from '@angular/forms';
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';
import {Subscription} from 'rxjs/Subscription';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appLimitTo]',
})
export class LimitToDirective implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    @Input('appLimitTo') limit: number;

    private subscription: Subscription;

    constructor(private ngControl: NgControl) {}

    ngOnInit() {
      const ctrl = this.ngControl.control;

      this.subscription = ctrl.valueChanges
        .pipe(map(v => (v || '').toString().slice(0, this.limit)))
        .subscribe(v => ctrl.setValue(v, { emitEvent: false }));
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
      this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

usage:

```
<input ngModel appLimitTo="3" type="number" />
```

[Live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-utysvr)

Comment: You've probably initialized the `ngModel` to null. Check out my edit. The map function now looks like this: `map(v => (v || '').slice(0, this.limit))`

Comment: No have checked... It's not like that... I've tried to check the `v` using if but still, the same error arises... Is there an alternative way to do so.... using `ElementRef` and Events?

Comment: Please tell me how to fix it?

Comment: note that you should unsubscribe on destroy to avoid mem leaks

Comment: I'm aware of that. I wanted to keep the example as simple as possible as not to confuse the OP. It was probably a bad idea, because I should not have assumed that OP knows about unsubscribing. I'll edit it now.

Comment: FYI. OP is using `type="number` so this solution will throw the error OP mentions. This stackblitz works because it isn't type number. It can easily be fixed by changing `(v || '').slice` to `(v || '').toString().slice`.

Comment: Fixed it. Thank you for the comment :)

Comment: Everything is working fine with directive except 1 thing. It is not allowing the user to enter 0. How can I fix this?